# Android taking pictures asynchronously inside a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-camera, intentservice

I have been struggling with the above for a while now, so would really appreciate any answers.

Firstly, my main aim is to take a picture when I receive an intent ( inside a broadcast receiver). 
I have tried quite a few approaches to the above but to no avail. 
The following (showing relevant code snippets for visual clarity) code illustrates one approach:

```
public class ArduinoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
takePictureUsingCamera();
}    }
```

The function  takePictureUsingCamera() calls a function in a class that deals with the camera ( e.g displaying a camera preview in a FrameLayout). The particular function calls the android takePicture function in android:
    this.mPreview.mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this.mPicture);

However when I receive the intent, the app crashes. I felt that the reason behind this was that taking a picture was perhaps asking for too much work to be done inside the broadcast receiver. (I tested this functionality using a simply picture capture using a button and it worked perfectly. )

So, the second approach that I tried was to create a Intentservice which will deal with the taking of pictures ( and other relevant tasks like storing pictures), when an intent is received.

The Service's onHandleIntent(Intent intent) method will now have the this.mCameraView.takePicture(filename) function. However, I need to pass my CameraView class as an object to this service using the intent. For this, I created a Serializable class and tried passing this using the intent's putExtra method. After a few crashes, I realized that the CameraView Class was not serializable (it is displaying the camera preview in a FrameLayout).

Another alternative way I thought of doing the above was to create the cameraView object itself inside the new service but for this I need the context and the reference to the main activity - which I don't think can be passed using intents. 
This leaves the option of starting a new activity to take the picture inside the broadcast receiver - again looks like doing too much work.
As I said before, I've tried a few approaches but haven't achieved success in any of them. I personally didn't think its going to be such a problem. I would really appreciate and be quite thankful to any answerers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do but it sounds like you want to trigger something (take a picture) to happen when you get a broadcast?

To do that you can create a Handler inside your main activity and then send a message to it when you receive the broadcast.  Something like this in your activity.

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override 
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                        takePicture();
                    }
});

broadcastReceiver = new YourReceiverClass(myHandler);

intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            "your_package_name.YourReceiverClass");
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

And something like this in the receiver

```
private Handler handler;
public YourReceiverClass(Handler handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
}

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (handler != null) {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks npn, that's exactly what I want to do - trigger taking a picture to happen when I get a broadcast. I'll try the above solution now and comment again if it works(or not).

Comment: Hi npn, I tried the above solution. however, the app crashes on taking the picture.I het the following error message :  java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed at
android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method) at
android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:948) .Any suggestion s why this might be happening or how to go about debugging this.

Comment: I am far from an expert at debugging, but for me when I do get a traceback, i look back through the message until I find a call from my code.  For example I image what you just posted above is the top of the traceback message?  If so look further down and try to find which statement in your code triggered this traceback.  Then you can either set a break point in the debugger or use Log.d("myTag", "some useful info");

Comment: Thanks very much. Yes these were the top three lines of the debugger, I located the line which actually causes the error :  this.mPreview.mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this.mPicture);  I put System.out.println("Useful info") before and after this line and as expected something in this function goes wrong - which I surprising as it executes flawlessly when simply called from a command button click. I''m still to figure out why this happens - but many thanks for the above help.

Comment: and you are calling it exactly the same way?  I am thinking whatever code you execute from the button should be called in the handleMessage.  For example if the onClick for the button calls blah() which has the command to take the picture then the handleMessage method should also call blah();

Comment: Yes, I am indeed calling them in the exact same way.I think its something particular with the method takePicture(null, null, this.mPicture) which makes it crash in a Handler but not when called from a button. I'll debug it further and post here if I manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after struggling with the above for a while and taking into above suggestion of using a handler, I still haven't got to the full solution. However, after some testing, the app seems to crash after taking a couple of pictures. This also the case with taking pictures while clicking the capture button.

Currently, I'm using the following code for the handler :

```
    Handler myHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
{
@Override 
public void handleMessage(Message msg)
{
System.out.println("HANDLER received a message");
takePictureUsingCamera();
}
};
```

I think this is to do with some advanced android concept ? Perhaps something is running out of memory ? I'll really appreciate if anyone can give me some suggestions based on the above observation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not a simple task. I am doing exatcly the same thing inside my application.
Basically the flow is simple - when you got the broadcast, you should start your Service / IntentService which will do the following:

- Get the params from the BroadcastReceiver
- Acquire the partial wakelock
- Start the new thread which is openning the camera, initializing with all needed parameters (resolution of the image, compression, etc), provide the camera preview window (this is a problematic part, i will cover it later on), check the autofocus and start it, get the callback from autofocus and take the picture. in the callback you will have the binary data of the picture. Don't forget to close the camera at the end.

Now regarding the preview surface - the problem here that you don't have Activity context thus the preview window will be "virtual" window only with NULL surface. And this fact makes a lot of problems on different devices - on some of them it will work, on others it will fail.
The code to create this window is

```
cameraPreview = new SurfaceView(_serviceReference.get());
cameraPreview.setZOrderOnTop(true);                
cameraPreview.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
camera.setPreviewDisplay(cameraPreview.getHolder());
camera.startPreview();
```